# load .mat files with the same prefix name in matlab (e.g. load abc*.mat)

Tags: matlab, load, wildcard, mat

I have many .mat files in a folder that has the same prefix, for example `abc***.mat`.
Is there a way to use a wildcard type for loading files?
I can write `dir abc*.mat` and get the list of files but I can't `load abc*.mat`...

Thanks!

Comment: Just loop over the list returned by `dir`.

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping there was a way without a for loop for that, but following Cris Luengo (thanks!) suggestion here is a way to accomplish that.

```
temp=dir('abc*.mat');
for ii=1:numel(temp)
    load(temp(ii).name);
end
```